# How to determine the extrema(min&max) of a dynamic interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have an array of 200 in length.
Each second I have a new number added to the position [0] of the array pushing the other values up one position on the array.

What I need is to determine the max and min value for the entire array each time I feed it a new number. I need to analyze all the 200 values before a new one is fed to the array.

I've managed to do so, but I encountered some trouble discarding the 'old' max and 'old' min, since once they are pushed out of the array, I don't need them anymore.

I found a way of doing this by using the 1st differential and pushing the actual value in to another array. The problem there was that when I have a min or max appearing multiple times. This new array would have them repeated in no particular order and I want just one max and one min.

Comment: Could you provide an actual example? I don't understand which issue you are having. It sounds like you are also removing elements from the array, is that correct?

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in `max` and `min` functions?  They take arrays: `Math.max.apply(null, array)`.

Comment: @Jaxo they are `O(N)`, that's what is "wrong"

Comment: An array with 200 numbers isn't going to be any sort of bottleneck, though.

Comment: @Jaxo yep, but from algorithms point of view it's a nice task :-) Sometimes developers need a challenge other than just using `Math.max()` :-)

Comment: It actually might be "`O(N)` worst case" (with `O(1)` the best) if you keep the index of min/max value and compare with the new one.

Comment: I guess you could sort the array with whatever algorithm is fastest (heapsort?), then take the first and last indexes of it for *true* speed.

Comment: @Jaxo it won't help - the queue moves.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of n values which is updated at intervals by removing the first element and pushing a new one at the end then you can split the algorithm which finds the min/max of the interval in two steps.

Your precondition allows you to make a strong assumption which is the fact that

```
min(data) = min(data[0], data[1..n-1])
```

Starting from this assumption you don't need to calculate the min/max on all values at each step.

Let's make an example, suppose like you said, to have 200 values and to have a generic `min` function able to calculate the minimum of an array, a pair of values or a value and an array. It's metacode, ignore the syntax.

You start by precomputing the minimum and additional support data:

```
int middleMin = min(array[1..n-1]); // so we skip first
int firstValue = array[0];
int realMin = min(firstValue, middleMin);
```

Now, when you insert a new element at the end and remove the first two things can happen:

- `firstValue == realMin ( && firstValue < middleMin)`, in this case you must find the next higher value on the new `array[0..n-1]` since you removed the minimum
- `middleMin == realMin` in this case you know that the removed element wasn't the first so you don't need to recompute the global minimum, you just need to update it according to the new inserted element, eg `middleMin = realMin = min(realMin, array[n-1])`
- actually it can also happen that `firstValue == middleMin` but this falls back to second case since there is another value in the trail array which is the current minimum.